# Build a program with mingw on linux and run under wine --- UTF-8 support

Tags: c, utf-8, mingw-w64, wine

I have C code that prints some characters. I would like to see these characters printed, as opposed to an alphabet soup,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const char* test = "Greek: αβγδ; German: Übergrößenträger";
    printf("%s\n", test);
}
```

What works:

1. Native Linux compilation: `gcc test.c -o test && ./test`
2. Winegcc compilation: `winegcc test.c o test.exe && ./test.exe`
3. MinGW64 compilation *when the output is not a terminal* : `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.exe test.cpp && wine ./test.exe | cat`

All three commands print `Greek: αβγδ; German: Übergrößenträger` to the terminal.

What doesn't work:

1. MinGW64 compilation *when the output is a terminal*: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.exe test.cpp && wine ./test.exe`

This prints `Greek: Î±Î²Î³Î´; German: ÃbergrÃ¶ÃentrÃ¤ger` to the terminal.

It looks like the MinGW runtime detects if the output is a terminal/console, and does exactly the wrong thing.

What I have tried:

1. `system("chcp 65001");` — same output (the chcp command succeeds).
2. `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -fexec-charset=utf8 -finput-charset=utf8` — same output.
3. `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` — same output.
4. `wineconsole cmd` and run `.\test` from there — same output.
5. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 wine ./test.exe` — same output.
6. `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);` — no output at all.
7. Most combinations of the above — no dice.

What I have not tried yet:

1. Compiling with a Microsoft compiler under Wine.
2. Compiling with MinGW under Wine.
3. Compiling and/or running the program under real Windows with either compiler.

How can I fix the non-working case?

Comment: <rant>Character encoding is a PITA on Windows.</rant> Concerning compiling with a M$ compiler on Wine: By personal experience I know that you cannot install such a compiler, Wine is not accepted as base OS, the installation fails. -- I tried MinGW for Windows on Wine, and it produces the same result like yours.

Comment: Compiling with MinGW on native Win10 and running in CMD works, if `chcp 65001` is used.

Comment: You need a bigger bounty than 250 points to fix the cesspool that is character encoding on Windows.

Comment: @tripleee Actually UTF-8 started to work out of the box in Windows since, um, not sure, this year? But Wine of course lags behind.

Comment: Sure, if you limit the target to Windows 11 exclusively, it's probably easier.

Comment: Looks like extended ASCII printing instead of UTF-8. Since it's the terminal, have you tried different terminals in Windows?

Comment: @Surge I have no idea what extended ASCII is. Please read carefully what I wrote. There is no Windows, there is Wine. I use a linux terminal which doesn't have any problem with displaying UTF-8..  `wine ./test | cat` works perfectly well. ``wine ./test` doesn't.

Comment: I read your question carefully, and was not sure where you run your code. I was thinking maybe you're using a emulator on windows. Extended ASCII is an old standard that encodes the 2nd half of the 8 bit range. There are a number of versions, and it seems that the junk you see on the screen uses characters from that range. Based on your test, the binary must be the same, but wine seems to print 8 bit characters to the screen when you don't pipe the output.

Comment: @Surge "old standard ... number of versions" There is a number of versions indeed, but it is not a standard by any stretch of imagination. It is a moniker that some people slap on different ad-hoc non-standard encoding schemes. That's why I'm saying that I have no idea what it is. "wine seems to print 8 bit characters to the screen when you don't pipe the output" That's exactly the problem. Wine (or the mingw C runtime) detect that the output is a terminal and do unwanted things for reasons unknown.

Comment: I understand. I'm thinking now that it's likely that wine has to interact with stdout a certain way because it has to assume it is used by Windows style applications. Windows is notorious for the two byte wide character encoding they still use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked it up, and was told that `wprintf()` usually works with "wide" character formats (e.g. more than one byte character formats). I don't usually use C so I was also curious about how you force a UTF-8 output.

Also, this from `locale.h` might help:

```c
    // Set the console to support UTF-8 output
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
```

Comment: wprintf together with _setmode works but only with wchar_t strings (%ls format).

Comment: Well it is the only one, and it works.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It's not UTF8 though. :( Or is our only option manually reencoding into UTF16?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is not UTF-8 in the program source/data, but it is UTF-8 in the output stream, which is what I'm after (the runtime recodes it according to _O_U8TEXT mode). On WINE, recoding to UTF-16 so that the runtime recodes it back to UTF-8 looks like the only option. On Windows proper UTF-8 works for quite some time now with no need to jump through hoops.